# Python регулярные выражения, выдернуть нужные слова в list

Tags: python, django, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой текст

```
srt = "
<p><strong>Услуга:</strong>&nbsp;orders.Orders.service</p>
Название - orders.Orders.123name<br>
Заказ номер orders.Orders.id
"
```

как написать регулярное выражение, чтобы из текста выдернуть все слова `name1.name2.name3`

то есть на выходе `list = ['orders.Orders.service', 'orders.Orders.123name', 'orders.Orders.id']` итд

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Еще вариант использовать `re.finditer`. В этом случае можно варьировать количеством искомых групп атрибутов.

```
import re
srt = """
<p><strong>Услуга:</strong>&nbsp;orders.Orders.service</p>
Название - orders.Orders.123name<br>
Заказ номер orders.Orders.id
orders.Orders2
"""

finds = [f.group(0) for f in re.finditer('(\w+(\.\w+){2})', srt)]  
# Фильтрует только последовательность attr_1.attr_2.attr_3. 
# Вариант attr_1.attr_2 будет отброшен
```

или

```
finds = [f.group(0) for f in re.finditer('(\w+(\.\w+)+)', srt)]  
# Фильтрует любую последовательность attr_1.attr_2...attr_n
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот рабочий код на основе комментария  [ClickName](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/251986/clickname)

```
    import re
    def q_1320348(s):
        return re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+', s)
    s = "<p><strong>Услуга:</strong>&nbsp;orders.Orders.service</p>Название -\
    orders.Orders.123name<br>Заказ номер orders.Orders.id"
    print(q_1320348(s))
```

Comment: а как добавить символ подчеркивания? допустим текст такой orders.Orders.service_id. Сейчас выдергивает все до знака _

Comment: такой шаблон:
[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]
читаем тут:
https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def q_1320348(s):
    return re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+', s)
s = "<p><strong>Услуга:</strong>&nbsp;orders.Orders.service_id</p>Название -\
orders.Orders.123name<br>Заказ номер orders.Orders.id"
print(q_1320348(s))
```